# Team Foundation Server Peer Reviews

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Once a peer review has been completed and the developer has fixed all comments, how does the developer submit the peer review again to make sure all code/comments have been corrected?

Comment: Are you talking about TFVC code reviews, or Git pull requests?

Comment: Team Foundation peer reviews

Comment: There is nothing called "team foundation peer reviews". I gave you the two options.

Comment: We are using Team Foundation Version Control

Comment: I have found the answer.....

https://simpleprogrammer.com/git-vs-tfvc/

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer

Updating a Review Request With TFVC

In TFVC, the developer working on the coding—or the coder—can send code changes that are not yet committed to a branch, to the reviewer. In essence, the coder is sharing a shelveset with the reviewer.

The reviewer then can make comments to improve the code and mark the review as “Needs work.” After that, the coder makes the necessary changes and has to create another review request.

The big downside here is that this second review request doesn’t have any connection with the first one. This means that the reviewer has to review all the changes, not only the last improvements. So for each improvement, the reviewer gets a new review request and has to review the whole thing again.

https://simpleprogrammer.com/git-vs-tfvc/